# Htaccess ReWrite entire from tags to tag

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2.4

I made a mistake with my wordpress wordpress site and have a lot of pages going to

- www.mysite.com/tags/the-tag

when is should

- www.mysite.com/tag/the-tag

I tried the following but to no avail:

```
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)$ /tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```

anyone got any ideas

Comment: Remove the ^ from the beginning

Comment: Nope still no luck

Comment: Show your full .htaccess file including your wordpress rules.

Comment: Make sure above 301 rule is just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Answer (score 0):

I think You forgot to turn on the Engine

```
 RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)$ /tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you explain shortly what exactly is happening ?